# Right-aligned line-break with long verses in verse

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, verse, french

I'm happily using the `verse` environment to typeset French poetry.
However, I'm unsatisfied with the behavior of long-line breaks (when the verse is too long to fit on the page).

The `verse` behavior is to do:

```
Most of verses are short
here is another
foo bar bar foo long things will at one moment
      break on another line
another short
```

What French typesetting convention requires is:

```
Most of verses are short
here is another
foo bar bar foo long things will at one moment
                          [break on another line
another short
```

It's to say long line remainder part right-aligned, starting with an opening bracket, while the normal lines are still left aligned.

Any ideas on how to change this behavior?

Comment: a similar problem was addressed in appendix d ("dirty tricks") in the texbook.  it's in section 7 (p.392ff), "paragraph maneuvers", and it was devised to handle long entries in the key index of *math reviews*.  it redefines spaces so that, on running out of space at the end of a line, the line is broken automatically, with the beginning flush left, and the end flush right.  it's plain tex of course, but someone with better plain-to-latex skills than i can certainly adapt it.  @Yiannis' answer works, but could be more automatic.  i'd also suggest `\obeylines' to make input more natural.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Barbara. I read the book's part. Unfortunately, it's far beyond my understanding of LaTeX…

Answer (score 3):

This can be set using TeX's paragraph settings as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand*{\justlastragged}{%
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
\rightskip=-\leftskip
\parfillskip=\leftskip
\parindent=0pt}
\begin{document}
\justlastragged
This is a short poem line to see\\
what is this?

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

The image below shows the result.

[image]

To enter the break and have an automatic "[" inserted use the following short definition:

```
\def\c[{\\\relax[$\!$}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
\justlastragged
This is a short poem line to see\c[ 
what is this?
```

**Edit:**

A different method closer to what the OP wants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\X{\rightskip0pt \leftskip=0pt \parfillskip=0pt plus 1.0fil}
\long\def\B#1\par{%
\par
\rightskip0pt plus 1pt
\leftskip=0pt plus 2fill
\parfillskip=0pt  [#1{\par}\X}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\hsize3in
Another short line to test what is happening \B this is a  test

Some more test to just see what is happening here\B Testing another stanza

Testing etc 
\end{document}
```

Ultimately the best method might be the one commented by Barbara, where one makes the space character active, but that is a job for after Christmas! The second method works well, but one has to be careful with the `\hsize` to get it to the right value to make the poems look right.

Comment: It seems the OP *doesn't* want the first line ragged right, even in a `verse` environment with manual line breaks.

Comment: @lockstep First line is not a real ragged right line, if it is a full line. See the second example based on lipsum. I asked for a fuller example with a full stanza to understand better, what the OP needs. If all stanzas are two lines long then the `\def\c[` can be modified to provide simply an `\hfil[`.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides : Thanks :) I tried to be more clear/accurate in the question.

Comment: If your document isn't already that large you may consider using `reledmac`. See p. 50 of `reledmac.pdf`:

 "**9.6 Hanging symbol**

It is possible to insert a symbol in each line of hanging verse, as in French typography; for example, the opening bracket `[`. To insert it in `reledmac`, use macro `\sethangingsymbol{⟨h⟩}` with this code.

In the example of French typography, do

    `\sethangingsymbol{[\,}`

You can also use it to force hanging verse to be flush right:

    `\sethangingsymbol{\protect\hfill}`"

Answer (score 1):

If you want the broken part of the line on the right side of the page, you can also change the `\vindent` length to your preferred width to make it look right-aligned. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\setlength{\vindent}{0.6\textwidth}   % indent percent of page width

\begin{document}
\begin{verse}
    Some really really reallyreallyreally really really really really long line
\end{verse}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `gmverse` does the job. You even have the bracket option with `squarebr`, everything is explained here : [How to Left-align first line in a paragraph, right-align others](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172401/how-to-left-align-first-line-in-a-paragraph-right-align-others)

Comment: Welcome to the website of TeX.SE users. Could you please propose your own solution?