# How to Left-align first line in a paragraph, right-align others

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to typeset a song and for cases where one verse is longer than a line, I'd like to have the first line left-aligned and the second one right-aligned. Is there any way to achieve this automatically without the need to insert manual breaks?

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39233/right-aligned-line-break-with-long-verses-in-verse

Comment: Right aligned with respect to what?  the right margin of the page, or with respect to the end of the first line?  Also, being a verse, do you want manual line-breaking, or must it work with auto-breaking when it reaches the margin?

Comment: PaulStanley: thanks, but the code posted in reply of that question tends to right-align also all one-line verses, which is not what I want.

StevenB.Segletes: I'd like it to work with auto-breaking and align to the right margin.
  
Thank you both – but Bernard's answer seems to solve my problem :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gmverse` package does that: it has a `\versehandright` declaration that is executed by default, and, if the package is loaded with `squarebr` option, a `\versehandrightbr` declaration is available, that begins the second line with a square bracket as is usual in french poetry.

Here is an example of what we can obtain according to traditional French typography with the first page of André Breton's  poem *Pleine marge*. It combines the use of the `verse` and `gmverse`packages:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}%
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers = {OldStyle,Proportional}, Ligatures =Rare, StylisticSet={1,2,5}, WordSpace = 1.1}
\setmainfont{Sabon Next LT Pro}%
\setsansfont{Gill Sans Std}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[textwidth =14cm,textheight = 23cm, noheadfoot, marginratio={4:6,5:7}]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{verse, gmverse}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\renewcommand{\poemtitlefont}{\bfseries\LARGE\centering\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\stanzaskip}{1\baselineskip}

\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=5.0}PLEINE MARGE} \\\mbox{}\\ \textmd{\large André Breton (1896-1966)}\vspace{3\baselineskip}}

\epigraph{\itshape à Pierre Mabille}{}
\begin{verse}

Je ne suis pas pour les adeptes\\
 Je n’ai jamais habité au lieu dit La Grenouillière\\
 La lampe de mon cœur file et bientôt hoquette à l’approche des parvis%

Je n’ai jamais été porté que vers ce qui ne se tenait pas à carreau \\
Un arbre élu par l’orage\\
 Le bateau de lueurs ramené par un mousse\\
 L’édifice au seul regard sans clignement du lézard et mille frondaisons\\

Je n’ai vu à l’exclusion des autres que des femmes \\
qui avaient maille à partir avec leur temps\\
Ou bien elles montaient vers moi soulevées par les vapeurs d’un abîme\\

Ou encore absentes il y a moins d’une seconde elles me précédaient du pas de la Joueuse de tympanon\\
Dans la rue au moindre vent où leurs cheveux portaient la torche\\

Entre toutes cette reine de Byzance aux yeux passant de si loin l’outremer\\
Que je ne me retrouve jamais dans le quartier des Halles où elle m’apparut \\
Sans qu’elle se multiplie à perte de vue dans les glaces des voitures des marchandes de violettes\\

Entre toutes l’enfant des cavernes son étreinte prolongeant de toute la vie la nuit esquimau \\
Quand déjà le petit jour hors d’haleine grave son renne sur la vitre\\
```

\end{document}

[image]

Comment: An MWE would improve your answer immensely.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: You're right. I'll  try as soon as possible. Actually, I wondered how to realise it when I used Peter Wilson's `verse` package a couple of years ago and never was able able to do it. I discovered the aforementioned package very recently.