# Prevent "extreme" interword space stretch in multi-line title

Tags: spacing

The titles of my thesis are typeset in boxes where the text is justified, except for the last line, which is right aliged (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39233/right-aligned-line-break-with-long-verses-in-verse)):

```
% Justify all lines in  paragraph, except last line right aligned
\newcommand*{\justlastragged}{%
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
\rightskip=-\leftskip
\parfillskip=\leftskip
\parindent=0pt}
```

That works fine, except that it sometimes leads to ugly titles, where space is stretched too much. See for example the image below:

[image: Stretched space]

In this case, I would just want the top line to be left aligned. I don't want to set the text to be left aligned by default (instead of justified), since then other titles aren't typeset as nice (i.e. those where only a little stretch needs to be applied).

I have tried playing with `spaceskip`, but as soon as even the tiniest amount of "plus" stretch is added, the space in the image above gets expanded such that the whole line is filled. Another thing I tried is manually adding line breaks, but in that case, the title is treated as two paragraphs and both lines get right aligned.

Is there any way to accomplish what I want? Being able to set a limit to the maximum amount of stretch would seem nice, but I can't find anything like that.

**Edit**: Now with minimal sample:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Justify all lines in  paragraph, except last line right aligned
\newcommand*{\justlastragged}{%
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
\rightskip=-\leftskip
\parfillskip=\leftskip
\parindent=0pt}

% Left-align all lines in paragrahp, except last line right aligned
\newcommand*{\leftlastragged}{%
\leftskip=0pt plus 1fil
\rightskip=0pt plus 1fill
\parfillskip=0pt plus -1fill
\parindent=0pt}

\newcommand{\titlelayoutA}{\justlastragged \Large \scshape \bfseries}
\newcommand{\titlelayoutB}{\leftlastragged \Large \scshape \bfseries}

\begin{document}

% Using justified text
\parbox{2.5cm}{Justified}
\fbox{\parbox{3.2cm}{\titlelayoutA This is just a test}} % Look good
\hspace{0.5em}
\fbox{\parbox{3.2cm}{\titlelayoutA This does not fit}}   % Looks bad

\vspace*{2em}

% Using left aligned
\parbox{2.5cm}{Left-aligned}
\fbox{\parbox{3.2cm}{\titlelayoutB This is just a test}} % Looks bad
\hspace{0.5em}
\fbox{\parbox{3.2cm}{\titlelayoutB This does not fit}}   % Looks good

\end{document}
```

Comment: There's only one space that can be used for justifying the first line and PRNG doesn't fit. I can't see how to do this without using ragged left setting. Justifying titles is hardly a successful activity.

Comment: `\hfill` added by hand after `Secure` presumably does what you want though (although I agree with egreg that just always using ragged setting seems more common)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did some more tests, and using `\hfill\null\\ ` works for manual line breaks, which is what I'm currently using. I would prefer some automated way though.

Comment: @Darhuuk You get the first line raggedright and the last line raggedleft; if that's what you want, it can be made automatic. But I'd simply prefer `\raggedleft` for all titles.

Comment: @egreg That I can do as well, but that's not really the point of the question. What I'm looking for is a way to let LaTeX to stretch a space only to a given limit.

Comment: @Darhuuk If you only have a space and want to justify, that space will be used; TeX stretches a stretchable glue as much as needed to fill the line as prescribed and this can't be changed; you might use a stretchable `\rightskip`, but the typographical result will be dubious.

Comment: @egreg Ah, so there's no way to automatically do what I want then. Good to know though, now I can stop my search! Manual fixes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If TeX is ordered to fill a certain width, for instance to justify a line, it will use all available stretchable glue.

The amount of stretching specified in the glue is only used for computing the badness of the line, but if you say

```
\hbox to 5em{M\hskip 1em plus 1em M}
```

the glue will be stretched as much as needed to accomplish the task. Let's assume for simplicity that “M” is 1em wide; the space to be filled up is 5em, but only 3em are covered by the material; so the glue has to stretch for 2em and so the stretch factor is 2, which brings to a badness of 800 (the badness is approximately 100 times the cube of the stretch factor, but it's 10000 if that number exceeds 10000).

There is no way to tell TeX to limit the stretchability of glue, except adding some other (finite) glue so that it doesn't need to go beyond the stated limit.

One can typeset a line several times until the badness is 100, which means the stretch factor is 100. The macro `\nostretch` has two arguments: the first is the maximum allowed width, the second is the text to be typeset.

```
\def\nostretch#1#2{%
  \begingroup\hbadness=10000 % don't report high badness
  \dimen0=#1\relax
  \setbox0=\hbox to\dimen0{#2}\count255=\badness
  \loop\ifnum\count255>100
    \advance\dimen0-.5pt
    \setbox0=\hbox to\dimen0{#2}\count255=\badness
%    \hbox{\copy0\ -- \the\count255}% for debugging
  \repeat
  \box0
  \endgroup
}

\nostretch{5em}{M\hskip 1em plus 1em M}

\bye
```

If you remove the comment in the debugging line, you see the computations:

[image]

The last line is what would be printed without the debugging; it has 2 ems of space between the two M's (not really, because the width of M is not 1em in the `cmr10` font). Any glue would be used, including interword spaces.